# Get text from .txt and put in html

Tags: html

I would like to insert text from a .txt file into HTML for example:

```
<div class="pasteHere">
    <p>text from files/text.txt</p>
</div>
```

Been looking this up but I'm new to HTML and need a simple explanation. Also how would I paste only a certain line? example:

```
<div class="pasteHere">
    <p>line 1 from files/text.txt</p>
    <p>line 2 from files/text.txt</p>
    <p>line 3 from files/text.txt</p>
</div>
```

I need the information to come from a text file rather than manually inserting it or through variables

Comment: Which technology you are using for file reading? .net, php, java,python? Have you written any code so far for this?

Comment: You could either use an iframe (ugh!) or in order to load the text via javascript, read up on AJAX!

Comment: I was originally using an iframe but I would prefer to use actual text, I haven't done any code since I wouldn't know where to start this is in a wiki page though that only accepts HTML it allows me to use <style></style> though so I imagine it will also allow me to use <script></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)'s [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Here are the steps:

- include jQuery script file in your html. You can use CDN `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- Write script to load to text in file to web page. Observe the code bellow:

  ```
  <div class="pasteHere">
      <p id="fileTextHere">text from files/text.txt</p>
  </div>
  <script>
      $('#fileTextHere').load("[file url or location path]");
  </script>
  ```
- Give the file path inside load function without `[` `]` brackets

Note that if you are passing a system file path in load function it will not work in chrome because chrome only allows files over internet and not on local desktop. Firefox does allow it though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I've used the code you provided and was using hastebin as an example to see if I could grab text and add it to my page but it doesn't appear to be working it just displays "text" from the paragraph tag here is my [code](https://hastebin.com/ugulamijim.xml) my guess is it should display "testtext"

Comment: You are including jQuery after calling load function.
See the correct code [here](https://hastebin.com/gakoleweyo.xml)

Comment: ah, I've changed my code to your version but I'm still having the same problem it just displays 'text' rather than the 'test' message on the link

Comment: Found this error in the console.
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://hastebin.com/raw/izacavejih.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: The problem is with hastebin. See this code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VaTz88/9be355zy/1/) it's working.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem everything is fine now, really appreciate the support